# Equivalent of dayname('column_name')='what you want to specify' in PostgreSQL and Redshift?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, amazon-redshift

does anyone know what is the equivalent of << dayname(column_name)='what you want to specify' >> in PostgreSQL?

For example, to find out the list of users that created an account in the year of 2015 I can do:

```
WHERE YEAR(created_at)=2015
```

How can I do the similar thing in PostgreSQL & RedShift?

Answer (score 1):

To get the year from a date or timestamp, use [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

```
where extract(year from created_at) = 2015
```

Not sure what you mean with `dayname()` but it sounds as if you are looking for [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: Probably OP wants something like `date_part(?, created_at) = ?`. Just a theory.

Comment: @Abelisto: `date_part()` is the same as `exctract()` (with `extract()` being standard SQL)

Comment: I meant that the `date_part` function can accept parameter as its first argument. Thus `dayname(column_name)` is equal to `date_part(:dayname, column_name)`.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. I forgot to specify that what I meant by dayname()='something' is an operator in MySQL. An example would be month('column_name')=12

Comment: @rolladice: did you read the manual? That is exactly what `extract()` does

Answer (score 0):

You can get the day name from the date like:

```
select to_char( to_date(datecolumn, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'dy' ) from <table_name>;
```